# javascript does not recognize my html elements

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I get is a blank page, although I should have a combo box. The array gets filled just fine - I alerted some values and it works, but the combo box does not show anything.
What I want to do is create a combobox from the data retrieved from the array, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var array = {"ADDRESS_ID":["3","5"],"ADDRESS_PLACE":["a","b"],"ADDRESS_PARENT":[null,null],"TYPE":["0","1"]};
    var i, theContainer, theSelect, theOptions, numOptions, anOption;
    theContainer = document.createElement('div');
    theContainer.id = array['TYPE'][0];
    theSelect = document.createElement('select');
    theSelect.name = 'name_of_select';
    theSelect.id = 'id_of_select';
    theSelect.onchange = function () {
        alert('You selected option '+this.selectedIndex);
    };

    // Add some <option>s
    numOptions = array.length;
    for (i = 0; i < numOptions; i++) {
        anOption = document.createElement('option');
        anOption.value = array['ADDRESS_ID'][i];
        anOption.innerHTML = array['ADDRESS_ID'][i];
        theSelect.appendChild(anOption);
    }

    // Add the <div> to the DOM, then add the <select> to the <div>
    document.getElementById('container_for_select_container').appendChild(theContainer);
    theContainer.appendChild(theSelect);
    </script>
    <div id="container_for_select_container">

    </div>
    </body>         
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine apart from a few things. As mentioned the length of your Array is wrong. You need to have the `array['ADDRESS_ID'].length` instead of `array.length` and you need to either place the `div` with id 'container_for_select_container' before you JavaScript code or place your JavaScript code in a `window.load` function. Otherwise you are trying to append your select box to a HTML element that does not yet exist.

```
<div id="container_for_select_container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = {
        "ADDRESS_ID": ["3", "5"],
            "ADDRESS_PLACE": ["a", "b"],
            "ADDRESS_PARENT": [null, null],
            "TYPE": ["0", "1"]
    };
    var i, theContainer, theSelect, theOptions, numOptions, anOption;
    theContainer = document.createElement('div');
    theContainer.id = array['TYPE'][0];
    theSelect = document.createElement('select');
    theSelect.name = 'name_of_select';
    theSelect.id = 'id_of_select';
    theSelect.onchange = function() {
        alert('You selected option ' + this.selectedIndex);
    };

    // Add some <option>s
    numOptions = array['ADDRESS_ID'].length;
    for (i = 0; i < numOptions; i++) {
        anOption = document.createElement('option');
        anOption.value = array['ADDRESS_ID'][i];
        anOption.innerHTML = array['ADDRESS_ID'][i];
        theSelect.appendChild(anOption);
    }

    // Add the <div> to the DOM, then add the <select> to the <div>
    document.getElementById('container_for_select_container').appendChild(theContainer);
    theContainer.appendChild(theSelect);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with your `numOptions`. Shouldn't it be:

`numOptions = array['ADDRESS_ID'].length;`

instead of

`numOptions = array.length;`?

[**Here's the working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yJD3Z/)

Comment: well weird it works on fiddle but i already tried that and even if the length was 0 wouldn't it show an empty combo box which it's not the case it just shows nothing

Comment: Then in that case check your php code for any error. Also, try debugging the generated markup in developer console. Because in my fiddle, as you said, it shows up an empty combo box if length is zero. Goes to show problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your numOptions variable to:

```
numOptions = array['ADDRESS_ID'].length;
```

Working example in JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/reBSB/

New Code:

```
var array = {"ADDRESS_ID":["3","5"],"ADDRESS_PLACE":["a","b"],"ADDRESS_PARENT":[null,null],"TYPE":["0","1"]};
var i, theContainer, theSelect, theOptions, numOptions, anOption;
theContainer = document.createElement('div');
theContainer.id = array['TYPE'][0];
theSelect = document.createElement('select');
theSelect.name = 'name_of_select';
theSelect.id = 'id_of_select';
theSelect.onchange = function () {
    alert('You selected option '+this.selectedIndex);
};

// Add some <option>s
numOptions = array['ADDRESS_ID'].length;
for (i = 0; i < numOptions; i++) {
    anOption = document.createElement('option');
    anOption.value = array['ADDRESS_ID'][i];
    anOption.innerHTML = array['ADDRESS_ID'][i];
    theSelect.appendChild(anOption);
}

// Add the <div> to the DOM, then add the <select> to the <div>
document.getElementById('container_for_select_container').appendChild(theContainer);
theContainer.appendChild(theSelect);
```